# Непонятная ситуация с DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Есть две почти одинаковые ситуации. В первой контекст `DbContext` создается как поле, получает все данные из базы и этот лист привязывает к `DataGrid` и все работает. Во второй контекст `DbContext` создается через `using`, а дальше все так же, но данные которые помеченные как `virtual` в `DataGrid` не отображаются. Почему так ?

**UPDATE.**   Данные не помеченные как `virtual` тоже не отображаются.

**UPDATE 2** Если запустить приложение в режиме отладки из метода `ShowData`, и подождать пару секунд, то данные отображаются так как и нужно. Если пробежаться быстро по методу в отладке то все по старому.

**UPDATE 3.  Проблема до сих пор актуальная, хочу понять почему так.**

> Ситуация 1.

```
class MainVM:BaseVM
        {
            ContentStorage db = new ContentStorage();

            public MainVM()
            {
                ShowData();
            }

            private List<Storage> listStorage;

            public List<Storage> ListStorage
            {
                get { return listStorage; }
                set
                {
                    listStorage = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            private void ShowData()
            {
                var s = db.Storages.ToList();
                ListStorage = s;
            }

            public MainVM()
            {
                ShowData();
            }
        }
```

> Ситуация 2.

```
    class MainVM:BaseVM
    {
        private List<Storage> listStorage;

        public List<Storage> ListStorage
        {
            get { return listStorage; }
            set
            {
                listStorage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void ShowData()
        {
            using (var db = new ContentStorage())
            {
                var s = db.Storages.ToList();
                ListStorage = s;

            }
        }

        public MainVM()
        {
            ShowData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите тип объектов - он точно ваш `Storage` или там какие нибудь прокси объекты?

Comment: @Monk, Тип обьектов именно `Storage`.

Comment: Проблема по сути в том, что вы используете Binding к модельным объектам. Так делать не стоит.

Comment: @VladD, а как стоит делать?

Comment: Ну, тут пробегали вопросы на эту тему. Весь список, к которому происходит `Binding`, должен быть вычитан в VM-объекты. VM-объекты должны жить в UI-потоке, в отличие от работы с базой, которая должна быть в фоновом потоке (иначе тормоза).

Comment: @VladD, согласен с вами, но уж так удобно было использовать готовые модельные обьекты :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему, "данные помеченные как virtual" - это навигационные свойства.

EF по умолчанию не загружает связанные сущности. Вместо этого он создает класс-обертку поверх вашего Storage, переопределяя виртуальные свойства так, что они будут подгружены при первом обращении. Этот механизм называется Lazy Load.

Для его работы нужно чтобы контекст, из которого был загружен объект, был жив на момент обращения к свойству. В первом примере контекст жив - и все работает. Во втором - вы уничтожаете его сразу после получения списка. После уничтожения контекста все такие свойства будут бросать исключение (что, скорее всего, съедается гридом)

Вам стоит или держать контекст живым, или явно подгружать связанные сущности:

```
var s = db.Storages.Include("MyProperty").ToList();
```

Или

```
var s = db.Storages.Include(s => s.MyPropery).ToList();
```